# Как спозиционировать блок в правом нижнем углу?

Tags: css

Всем привет!

Есть скрипт, который выводит блок только ночью.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="charset" content="utf-8">
    <title>Окно</title>
    <style type="text/css">

    #mywindow2 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 25%;
        left: 25%;
        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
        background-color: #FFF9AE;
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    #closewin2 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 3px;
        right: 3px;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        background-color: #FFF9AE;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    </style>
    <script>
        function showWindow() {
            var myWindow1 = document.getElementById("mywindow1");
            var myWindow2 = document.getElementById("mywindow2");
            var nowDate = new Date();
            if (nowDate.getDay() == 0 || nowDate.getDay() == 6) {
                myWindow1.style.visibility = "visible";
            }

            else if (nowDate.getHours() <= 8 || nowDate.getHours() >= 21 ) {
                myWindow2.style.visibility = "visible";
            }
        }
        function closeWin(obj) {
            var myWindow = obj.parentNode;
            myWindow.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
        window.onload = showWindow;

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mywindow2">
    <div id="closewin2" onclick="closeWin(this)">Закрыть</div>
    Ночь
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Как можно спозиционировать выскакивающий блок справа снизу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно [попробовать так](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/RaL8S/):

```
#mywindow2 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: #FFF9AE;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает :-)

Comment: А как ещё можно сделать, чтобы при наведении на "Закрыть" был курсор мышки.

Comment: @laboomba, В смысле "курсор мышки"? Может это имели в виду?

    #closewin2 {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

Answer (score 1):

Смотри правило {cursor:pointer;}

Comment: Я уже нашёл это правило. Но всё равно, спасибо большое.